# How can I drag the last element of ListView.builder up to a certain distance?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, scroll

I want the last element of ListView.builder to be stretched upwards by the distance I set, but BouncingScrollPhysics() allows the last element to be stretched almost to the middle of the screen. How can I change it to custom? What lines of code should I change? [problem](https://youtu.be/MpVcfr4tnA8?si=YtkwhJJfVwkhP0Qu)

Comment: Welcome to SO! For better understanding of your question, please provide a code. Also, the link seems to be broken